# How can I set pentaho report update frequency?

Tags: reporting, business-intelligence, pentaho

With pentaho reporting software, I create report based on MYSQL query. It took much time to generate my report. Then I want to publish it to pentaho bi-server.

How can I set update frequency for my report, instead of generate every time I open it?

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule a report to run on a repeated basis on the bi server.  Once you've published the report, right click and select "Schedule...".

Comment: so if it is set, when I open a report, it will read report cached instead of generate instantly?